# How can I install the latest jdk 9 using terminal command on ubuntu 16.04 LTS ?

Tags: 16.04, java, jdk, ide

I have jdk 8 on my ubuntu desktop. I need to install the latest jdk 9 for Java programming. What are the commands for Java programming and IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

Update your `environment variable` after that

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Add / Edit this line

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle"
```

Save and run

```
source /etc/environment
```

Test if environment variable was set

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

(Optional) For Linux Mint Users:

```
sudo apt install gsfonts-x11 oracle-java9-set-default
```

**Update**: Oracle Java 9 has reached end of life. Users of Java SE 9 should switch to Java SE 10. [Source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html)

To install Java 10, follow this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java10-installer
```

[Source](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/install-oracle-java-10-in-ubuntu-or.html)

Comment: should we add JRE also to `/etc/environment`?

Comment: not necessary :)

Comment: Update: Oracle Java 9 has reached end of life: [Read](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can see which versions are available in your PPA's:

```
sudo apt-cache search java-sdk
```

If you want something else that this is suggest using SdkMan

```
https://sdkman.io
```

After install see what it can give you by:

```
sdk list java
```