# Error while installing Oracle JDK 9 Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java, 17.10, jdk, oracle

I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 17.10. Now I'm trying to install Java 9 on Ubuntu. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961300/how-can-i-install-the-latest-jdk-9-using-terminal-command-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)
askubuntu answer and when I run `sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer` this is what I'm getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 oracle-java9-set-default
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core
  ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho
  | ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 oracle-java9-installer oracle-java9-set-default
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 35.2 kB/42.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 231 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu artful/main amd64 oracle-java9-installer amd64 9.0.1-1~webupd8~0 [30.8 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu artful/main amd64 oracle-java9-set-default amd64 9.0.1-1~webupd8~0 [4,442 B]
Fetched 35.2 kB in 2s (13.2 kB/s)                   
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java9-installer.
(Reading database ... 256251 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java9-installer_9.0.1-1~webupd8~0_amd64.deb ...
oracle-license-v1-1 license has already been accepted
Unpacking oracle-java9-installer (9.0.1-1~webupd8~0) ...
Setting up oracle-java9-installer (9.0.1-1~webupd8~0) ...
No /var/cache/oracle-jdk9-installer/wgetrc file found.
Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk9-installer/wgetrc and
using default oracle-java9-installer wgetrc settings for it.
Downloading Oracle Java 9...
--2018-01-17 06:08:30--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.1+11/jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.66.247.173
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.66.247.173|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.1+11/jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz [following]
--2018-01-17 06:08:30--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.1+11/jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 118.214.58.117, 2402:d000:130:281::2d3e, 2402:d000:130:289::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|118.214.58.117|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.1+11/jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516149631_fbfbf47dc4fd2a5e471045e2cd2db76f [following]
--2018-01-17 06:08:33--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.1+11/jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516149631_fbfbf47dc4fd2a5e471045e2cd2db76f
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.66.247.173|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-01-17 06:08:34 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 9 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java9-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why the download fails and Oracle JDK 9 is not installing. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Same issue that I'm having here: https://askubuntu.com/q/996774/783699 Basically the PPA isn't maintained by Oracle themselves, but rather a third party. Today Oracle released 9.0.4 and it broke `apt` for JDK. There will be workarounds soon and eventually they'll update the PPA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to download Oracle Java 9 manually from the official Oracle website at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html and the link to download jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz is working. Your other alternative is to install openjdk-9-jdk from the default Ubuntu 17.10 repositories.

[Install Oracle Java JDK the manual way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre/55960?s=2|44.2509#55960)

If you have problems getting Java 9 to work properly with React JavaScript library, don't give up because you can have multiple versions of Java installed alongside each other and set the Java version from the terminal by following the instructions in [How to set default Java version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version).